# Apollo Client - [BatchHttpLink]: Error writing result to store for query

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I'm having trouble to batch queries using ApolloClient when I'm calling `BatchHttpLink` in my client. I've opened a issue on `react-apollo` repo where you can check with more details my code:

https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1656

basically seems like initially Apollo is doing the right thing: batching the queries and returning the results properly, but I'm getting the following error on my console:

```
    ApolloError.js:34 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Error writing result to store for query:
     query CategoriesServicesQuery {
      categories {
        id
        name
        slug
        tags {
          id
          slug
          name
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
    }

    Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined
        at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:34)
        at QueryManager.js:277
        at QueryManager.js:664
        at Array.forEach ()
        at QueryManager.js:663
        at Map.forEach ()
        at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (QueryManager.js:658)
        at QueryManager.js:226
        at
```

the response looks like:

```
    [
      {
        query: ,
        variables: ,
      },
      {
        query: ,
        variables: ,
      },
      {
        query: 
        variables: ,
      }
    ]
```

I believe, somehow under the hood, Apollo should handle this and return `this.props.data` to the respective app components.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.